# Github configuration for school

Tags: git, github

I'm planning on using github for a highschool computing class. I'm not sure of the best way to structure it in terms of organisations, teams, etc. I'd like to have a repository containing code samples and starting points for student exercises, which each student then forks. Is there any point in setting up an organisation for this? What sort of setup do you use to handle new years/semesters? Has anyone got any experiences in doing something like this?

Comment: my mentor taught me version control without pushing code into github/bitbucket. `mercurial` got its own local server where you can push code into. im not sure if `git` has this kind of feature though

Answer (score 2):

One option is to emulate the open source model. Have students not only clone your code to their machines but properly fork it on github. Then show them how to make pull requests.

Students can organically work with each other by appointing a "leader" (benevolent-dictator-for-life in open source speak) and his repo will be the "central" repo for the team. Then the rest make pull requests to him or he can add them as contributors to his repo.

The starting learning curve is a bit higher (unless the student in question have contributed to open source projects) but after that it's quite seamless since that's how git was originally designed to be used.

Comment: And as a side-effect, your students will hopefully be more encouraged to look at and contribute to open source projects since they now know how to do it.

Comment: I would just advise that you be somewhat weary and make sure to make backups if you spend a lot of time creating an assignment and grant inexperienced git users direct read/write access.

Comment: By "you" I presume you mean the students because in this setup the lecturer need never grant write access or accept pull requests to his github repo

Comment: True, my point was more make sure you actually have a fork/copy of the repo and don't just rely on one belonging to an organisation which a student could nuke.

Answer (score 1):

A very good way of doing that is using Github's educational platform https://education.github.com/.

I would suggest you to create an [organization](https://help.github.com/articles/github-glossary/#organizations) for your class.
Each student will have an account and you will be able to control who has access to your organization and it's content.

You can create a repository with a folder for each student and require then to organize the homework/lesson inside each one of this folders. Every new homework you can require then to create a new branch and do Pool Request to the original repository. You could use the PR to add comments and request changes to your student's code and then encourage all the students to check each other's PR.

You will also be able to create multiple repositories inside the organization and manage user access level to each one of then, that's useful for exams and special projects.

Answer (score 0):

There is a point in using organisations if you want to put each assignment in its own repository and still provide a good overview of all the assignments.

Provided you use the fork model and public repositories you would only need to grant access rights to staff - so you would not need much in the way of teams.

There are several ways you could handle new years/semesters. One way would be to use a branch for each semester. Another is to update the assignment repositories at the end of each semester and assign a tag.

Comment: My answer was kind of oriented towards students doing individual assignments / review. @slebetmans answer is better if you want to teach collaboration.